# How to structure CRUD routes correctly in Angular projects?

Tags: angular, routes, angular-cli, lazy-loading, angular-router

**Question:** Does exist a best practice for defining single-page applications' routes?

In Angular projects functionality is generally separated in lazy-loaded modules, then the routes are configured in both `AppRoutingModule` and the lazy loaded modules.

Let's say the app will manage catalogs, for example: products. The routes could be configured like this:

**Option 1:**

- List: `/products`
- Create: `/products/create`
- Read: `/products/:id`
- Update: `/products/:id/edit`

It works, but looks a bit messy and there is some ambiguity between `/products/:id` and `/products/create` because the parameter `:id` can match the string "create". Example code:

app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            { path: 'products', loadChildren: 'app/products/products.module#ProductsModule' },
        ]
    }
];
```

products-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: ListProductsComponent },
    { path: 'create', component: CreateProductComponent },
    { path: ':id', component: ViewProductComponent },
    { path: ':id/edit', component: EditProductComponent },
];
```

**Option 2**

- List: `/products`
- Create: `/products/create`
- Read: `/product/:id` (notice "product" is singular)
- Update: `/product/:id/edit` (notice "product" is singular)

There is no ambiguity, but the configuration becomes messier:

app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            // Empty path. It works as long as the ProductsModule has no empty paths. You can define more lazy modules like this.
            { path: '', loadChildren: 'app/products/products.module#ProductsModule' },
        ]
    }
];
```

products-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'products', component: ListProductsComponent },
    { path: 'products/create', component: CreateProductComponent },
    { path: 'product/:id', component: ViewProductComponent },
    { path: 'product/:id/edit', component: EditProductComponent },
];
```

As you can see, when defining routes you have to consider the structure of the lazy modules and the "beauty" of the URLs.

What is the best practice for defining routes, specially for CRUD operations? Is there a good name convention?

Answer (score 6):

The only conventions/best-practices regarding Angular that I'm aware of come from the official [Style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide), it doesn't mention anything about routes. But definitely a recommended/good read.

Personally I would put 'create' and 'edit' into another module with a different root url.

```
admin/product/list
admin/product/edit/:id
admin/product/create
```

Else I'd use a slightly modified version of your Option 1.

```
List: /products
Create: /products/create
Update: /products/edit/:id
Read: /products/:id
```

#### Clean and easy to read code > "beauty" of the URLs

Comment: "Personally I would put 'create' and 'edit' into another module with a different root url."
Could you elaborate more, why would you do that ? or maybe edit your answer with example routing ?

Comment: It mainly comes down to providing some separation of concerns... 
The point would be to have a lazy loaded feature module with some route guards and such for admin related functions. Since the 'read' action is the most common action and doesn't usually require users to be authenticated (a least not in a catalog/products applications). While the 'create, update and delete' actions are different in nature.

Comment: Your modified version does not provide solution for the ops ambiguity between `/products/:id` and `/products/create`

Answer (score -7):

For CRUD apps, I don't like all file path style. Instead, I would prefer use additional parameters for actions.

```
enter code here
List: /products
Create: /products/;action=new
Update: /products/123456;action=change
Read: /products/123456;action=display
```

Please refer my lengthy blog on how to build real CRUD app: https://vincezk.github.io/Portal/